# Missing targets from nuget package in *.deps file

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have custom class library (SDK project) wrapping some CAN native drivers.
Scrap from *.targets file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <ItemGroup Label="NET_Libraries">
    <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)komodo_net.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Link>komodo_net.dll</Link>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

 ... (native libraries) ...
</Project>
```

When I reference this project in final application (.NET6) as project everything works well. But when I pack it as NuGet package and use it in this way, I've got:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'komodo_net, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've compared bin folders in both cases and find out, that issue is that these targets are missing in final *.deps.json file.

**Note**: when I delete this file app works - but that is not clear solution. Absolutely have no idea what causes this - can it be a bug in VS?

**Note2**: I've tried solution from thread [`#60609087`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60609087/visual-studio-2019-not-adding-referenced-projects-to-deps-json) - with no success

Use software:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022
Version 17.6.3
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.6.3+33801.468
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09032

Installed Version: Professional

Visual C++ 2022   00476-80000-00000-AA752
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022

ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.6.326.62524
ASP.NET and Web Tools

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.6.326.62524
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

C# Tools   4.6.0-3.23259.8+c3cc1d0ceeab1a65da0217e403851a1e8a30086a
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Devart Review Assistant   4.2.1033
Devart Review Assistant
Copyright (c) 2012-2023 Devart. All rights reserved.
Web: https://www.devart.com/review-assistant
Support: https://www.devart.com/review-assistant/support.html
Ordering: https://www.devart.com/review-assistant/ordering.html

Extensibility Message Bus   1.4.21 (main@8f226a8)
Provides common messaging-based MEF services for loosely coupled Visual Studio extension components communication and integration.

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   17.6.41 (790a401)
Support for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.

NuGet Package Manager   6.6.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.6.0.2327201+a6a61fdfa748eaa65aab53dab583276e26af4a3e
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

TypeScript Tools   17.0.20329.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.6.0-3.23259.8+c3cc1d0ceeab1a65da0217e403851a1e8a30086a
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development (Android)   17.0.33606.364
Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development (Android)

Visual F# Tools   17.6.0-beta.23174.5+0207bea1afae48d9351ac26fb51afc8260de0a97
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.

VisualStudio.DeviceLog   1.0
Information about my package

VisualStudio.Mac   1.0
Mac Extension for Visual Studio

VSPackage Extension   1.0
VSPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Xamarin   17.6.0.251 (d17-6@318364c)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   17.6.6.0 (remotes/origin/d17-6@cb430751d1)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates   17.6.32 (98c12a2)
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android SDK   13.2.0.6 (d17-5/a200af1)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
    Mono: 6dd9def
    Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d17-5@149d70fe
    SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.40.1@68c69d8
    Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d17-5@9f02d77


Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   16.4.0.6 (97731c92c)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
```

I've search for simillar issues and tried proposed solutions - with no success.
I need some advice.